# Passport control in different airports (Entry and Exit)

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Why is passport control and stamping random at different airports? 
Ex: once while leaving from Nuremberg to UK, I didn't have to go through the passport control. While when I traveled recently (in the same route), I had to go through the Passport control.

Comment: Travelers from Nuremberg (which is in the Schengen area) to the UK _should_ pass through Schengen exit controls at the airport where their flight to a destination outside Schengen departs. If you have had a case where this rule was not followed, something was wrong, but your brief description does not even allow a guess at _what_ went wrong. (Voting to close as too broad).